# TransactionScope with ReadCommited flag still returns uncommitted data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I'm using TransactionScope to manage transactions in EF, i need a ReadCommited behavior but it doesn't works as expected :

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                            new TransactionOptions() 
                                { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}))
{
    var c1 = customerRepository.Get(1);
    c1.FirstName = "Modified";
    customerRepository.Save();

    var c2 = customerRepository.Get(1);
    Assert.AreNotEqual("Modified", c2.FirstName);

    trans.Complete();
}
```

while i still didn't committed the transaction when getting the second instance, it's FirstName is already modified.

Comment: Can be this bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level
See this http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/02/01/few-things-about-pooled-connections/ for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inside the same transaction. The transaction isolation level refers to different transactions.

You can't isolate a translation from itself, but of other different transactions.

Try opening two different transaction scopes (i.e. with two apps running at the same time) and you'll see the effect os isolation between them. You can do this debugging two different apps at the same time, and pausing them before commiting the scope.

Look [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

As you can see, when each transaction isolation level is explained, it always refers to other transactions:

> READ UNCOMMITTED
>   Specifies that statements can read rows that have been modified by other transactions but not yet committed.
>
> READ COMMITTED
>   Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not committed by other transactions.
>
> REPEATABLE READ
>   Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions and ...

and so on.

Comment: For ReadCommitted, it says that volatile data cannot be read but can be modified. In the example above, is the volatile data the entire records of customerRepository or is it only the customer record whose Id is 1?